# javafxpackager error

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath, javafx

I try to pack my javafx project with javafxpackager. Everything works good (package is created), but I get error
Error: jfxrt.jar needs to be on classpath for -createbss and for -createJar without -nocss2bin
Ant script I use to call javafxpackager:

```
<exec executable="javafxpackager">
        <arg value="-createJar"/>
        <arg line="-classpath /jdk/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar"/>
        <arg line="-srcdir build"/>
        <arg line="-appclass org.shark.client.Shark"/>
        <arg line="-outdir packs"/>
        <arg line="-outfile Shark"/>
        <arg line="-manifestAttrs Main-Class=org.shark.client.Shark"/>
    </exec>
```

I absolutelly can't understand the reason.

Answer (score 1):

if you are already in ant why are you not useing javafx' ant extensions, I've not seen this problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra argument -nocss2bin to your exec block.  Converting the css to binary format is a performance optimization you would almost never really need anyway.

```
<exec executable="javafxpackager">
    <arg value="-createjar"/>
    <arg value="-nocss2bin"/>
    ...
</exec>
```

As you seem to be using ant already, I'd advise using the [JavaFX ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIACDJHC) rather than invoking the [javafxpackager](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packager.htm#CCHIHIIJ) through the exec block (same as tomsontom suggests).

Also note that, for java 7u12+, `jfxrt.jar` should be on the default execution path, so later java versions should not experience the issue you mention and explicitly setting `-nocss2bin` would no longer be required.